# How to make the inner value of a Result must_use

Tags: rust

I can use the `#[must_use]` attribute to mark a function as having a return value that must either be used or explicitly ignored:

```rust
#[must_use]
fn plain() -> i32 {
  1
}

fn main() {
  plain();  // warning
}
```

However, if I want to change my function so it now returns a `Result`, I cannot do this:

```rust
#[must_use]
fn result() -> Result<i32, ()> {
  Ok(1)
}

fn main() {
  result().unwrap();
}
```

because the call to `.unwrap()` counts as a "use", and the `#[must_use]` attribute is applying to the entire `Result`.

Is there a way to make `#[must_use]` apply to the inner type as well? Essentially I would like to make sure that the `i32` is not accidentally "eaten" by the semicolon.

I have the additional constraint that I cannot change the public API of this function, so I can't make it return a `Result<MustUse<i32>, ()>` or something along those lines.

Comment: _"I would like to make sure that the `i32` is not accidentally "eaten" by the semicolon"_ A means of [checking that the end of a function is never reached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62405398/how-to-statically-assert-the-end-of-a-function-is-unreachable) could help catch these.

Comment: _"I cannot change the public API of this function"_ But could you not create your own wrapper function?

Comment: If you estimate an API should return a inner must_use T, maybe you should ask them to do it.

Comment: For context, I own this function, but it has downstream crates that depend on this function. A breaking API change would require some coordination with the teams responsible for those crates. My suspicion is that what I'm asking for isn't currently possible, as I feel like it might require something like: `fn result() -> Result<#[must_use] i32, ()>`, which currently doesn't even parse

Comment: if you ask me everything expect `()` and `!` should be "must_use". I doubt `fn result() -> Result<#[must_use] i32, ()>` will ever been implemented. Also, must_use attribute is already a little special in Rust ecosystem.

Comment: Uh, changing from `i32` to `Result<i32, ()>` is already a breaking change. Why can't you also change `i32` into a wrapper type that has `#[must_use]` at the same time?

Comment: @kmdreko you have it wrong, the point of first snipped was to prove you can use must_use for i32

Comment: Yeah at the very least, I think it would be better if functions (other than `()` and `!` returning functions) were `#[must_use]` by default, and maybe a `#[ignorable_return_value]` for commonly-discared values, but perhaps it's too late for that (though maybe an editiion could help)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this by directly adding your own annotation to the `Result`, but you can do this trivially with a newtype:

```
#[must_use]
#[repr(transparent)]
pub struct MustUse<T>(T);

impl<T> From<T> for MustUse<T> {
    fn from(v: T) -> Self {
        Self(v)
    }
}

impl<T> MustUse<T> {
    #[must_use]
    fn into_inner(self) -> T {
        self.0
    }
}
```

Now, given this declaration:

```
fn result() -> Result<MustUse<i32>, ()> {
  Ok(1.into())
}
```

All of the following cause a warning:

- `result();` warns because `Result<_, _>` is must-use.
- `result().unwrap();` warns because `MustUse<_>` is must-use.
- `result().unwrap().into_inner();` warns because `MustUse<_>::into_inner()` is must-use.

(Note that you can bypass the warning by invoking a different, non-must-use method of `Result`, such as `result().ok()`, but that will be true no matter what you do.)

Comment: This does get the ideal compiler output, but unfortunately coordinating a change from `Result<i32, ()>` -> `Result<MustUse<i32>, ()>` probably pushes it into the category of "not worth the effort" from an organizational standpoint. Seems like this is the best possible given where the language is right now

Comment: Another way is to have alternative `unwrap()` that is marked `#[must_use]`.

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/hint/fn.must_use.html